# How to return a vector by reference implicitly expecting an empty vector as input?

Tags: c++, function, opencv, vector, reference

Let's say I have a vector of points and want to separate it into two other vectors within one function call. How would I best return these vectors.
My current approach is to give both desired output vectors to the function by reference.

```
void separatePoints(const vector<Point> &P, vector<Point> &P_1, vector<Point> &P_2)
{    
   for (size_t i = 0; i < P.size(); P++)
   {
     if (P[i].x < 100 && P[i].y < 100)
       P_1.push_back(P[i]);
     else 
       P_2.push_back(P[i]);
   }
}

vector<Point> P;
//.... this vector should be filled and contain some points
vector<Point> P_1, P_2; //not initialised
separatePoints(P, P_1, P_2);
```

When I do the abovementioned, it works well and as expected if the output vectors `P_1` and `P_2` are empty, else the Points would be appended to the vectors. If this is desired it would be ok, but what to do if it is not desired?

Of course I could create two new vectors in the function call and assign these vectors to `P_1` and `P_2` at the end of the function. But is this a good approach or is there some better way I'm missing at the moment?

```
void separatePoints(const vector<Point> &P, vector<Point> &P_1, vector<Point> &P_2)
{
   vector<Point> P_1_temp, P_2_temp;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < P.size(); P++)
   {
     if (P[i].x < 100 && P[i].y < 100)
       P_1_temp.push_back(P[i]);
     else 
       P_2_temp.push_back(P[i]);
   }
   P_1 = P_1_temp;
   P_2 = P_2_temp;
}
```

Comment: How about `P_1.resize(0); P_2.resize(0);`?

Comment: You could simply `P_1.clear(); P_2.clear();`.

Comment: You could clear them at first, or move the 2 local vectors at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use a return value and not reference or pointer arguments if you want to return a result. It makes the code easier to understand:

```
std::pair<std::vector<Point>, std::vector<Point>> separatePoints(const std::vector<Point> &P)
{
   std::pair<std::vector<Point>, std::vector<Point>> vectors;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < P.size(); P++)
   {
       if (P.x[i] < 100 && P.y[i] < 100)
           vectors.first.push_back(P[i]);
       else 
           vectors.second.push_back(P[i]);
   }
   return vectors;
}
```

If you dislike the nested template syntax of the `std::pair` declaration, define your own struct like

```
struct PointVectorPair {
    std::vector<Point> v1;
    std::vector<Point> v2;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a copy of the vectors? I agree in terms of readability, but is it also efficient in terms of computation?

Comment: @Phann: You mean when the pair is being returned? Probably not, most compilers do return value optimization in this case to avoid the copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass empty vector objects as non-const reference, or return them as `std::pair<std::vector<>,std::vector<>>`, or return them as `std::tuple`.

`std::pair`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

`std::tuple`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple